# Using c# to call google translator

Tags: c#, .net, translation, google-translate

I have to write some C# code which will enable me to translate a text file saved on my computer, using Google Translator. I want to write code to do this, but i am not sure where to start. I am new to this topic, but I think i have to download Google Translator API, but I'm not sure where to download this from. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion: It would be quicker to ask Google first http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENCH317&q=google+translation+api&aq=0s&oq=Google+Translator+API and look at the first result >;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try this http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/language/

Answer (score 4):

There is actually an open source project hosted on CodePlex named "Free language translator and file converter"

Here is the link: http://languagetranslator.codeplex.com/

This also use Google Translator service. As it is open source you can always see how it works. :-)

Comment: Any full source code sample about it ?  Whats about Apertium https://apertiumnet.codeplex.com/ ?