# C# translator with babel fish translator

Tags: c#, .net, translation

I need a translation in my C# code, babel fish translator. So far I have this code..but I always get the "error" string, something wrong with the regex part, can anyone help me with this one plz ?? thanks alot 

PS: IF there's any other way of coding will be oke

```
    public string Translate(string resource, System.Globalization.CultureInfo from, System.Globalization.CultureInfo to)
        {
            string[] VALIDTRANSLATIONMODES = new string[] 
 {"en_zh", "en_fr", "en_de", "en_it", "en_ja", "en_ko", "en_pt", "en_es", 
 "zh_en", "fr_en", "fr_de", "de_en", "de_fr", "it_en", "ja_en", "ko_en", 
 "pt_en", "ru_en", "es_en"};
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.babelfish.com");
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            //request.Referer = BABELFISHREFERER;
            string postsourcedata;
            string translationmode = "en_fr";
            postsourcedata = "lp=" + translationmode +
                "&tt=urltext&intl=1&doit=done&urltext=" +
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resource);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = postsourcedata.Length;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
            Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postsourcedata);
            writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            writeStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string page = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"<div style=padding:10px; lang=..>(.*?)</div>");
            MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(page);
            if (matches.Count != 1 || matches[0].Groups.Count != 2)
            {
                return "erro";
            }
            return matches[0].Groups[1].Value;



        }
```

Comment: i have a part in my code which returns "erro" it means the matchecollection is empty...

Comment: You are using code from a tutorial posted in 2004 (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/translation.aspx) and it's very likely that babelfish changed the html markup they send out and therefore your regex fails. Do a manual translation of a text there, examine the html source code and change your regex to capture the content you need.

Comment: yes im using that tutorial bcoz i didnt find any other one..thou i dono how to do id otherwise..thanks Till

Comment: Also, altavista babelfish was aquired by yahoo and can now be found at http://babelfish.yahoo.com/. The site running at www.babelfish.com today does not seem very automation-friendly as they require you to provide name and email-address in some ajax pop-ups in order to get to the translations. Probably not impossible, yet not as easy as you would hope for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats what i ended up doing

```
string fromCulture = from.Name;
            string toCulture = to.Name;
            string translationMode = string.Concat(fromCulture, "_", toCulture);

            string url = String.Format("http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt?lp={0}&tt=urltext&intl=1&doit=done&urltext={1}", translationMode, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resource));
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            string page = webClient.DownloadString(url);

            int start = page.IndexOf("<div style=\"padding:0.6em;\">") + "<div style=\"padding:0.6em;\">".Length;
            int finish = page.IndexOf("</div>", start);
            string retVal = page.Substring(start, finish - start);
```

Answer (score 1):

This previous answer might help: [Using c# to call google translator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679248/using-c-to-call-google-translator). It references this codeplex project: http://languagetranslator.codeplex.com/ which uses the Google Translation API.

It might take a few moments to find the code which does the job you want but I usually find that it's the best way to learn (for me at least!)

Comment: I need the translation with the babel fish translator :(

Comment: Are you sure it's babelfish.com you need? The old Alta Vista Babelfish is now at Yahoo, http://babelfish.yahoo.com/. If it is, you could try and ask the babelfish.com people if they have an API you could use? I'd think web-scraping like this isn't really allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is failing because there are no instances of what you are searching for in the downloaded text.

```
<div style=padding
```

does not exist. Perhaps some quotes?

```
<div style="padding //etc
```